# neo4j Auto indexing for a REST Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

Im trying to use auto indexing with the neo4j REST server (Community - 1.4.M04). This is in a Rails project, so im using the `neography` wrapper.

I couldnt find a consolidated tutorial online, from what i could follow from multiple blogs, here is what i did:

In conf/neo4j.properties:

```
node_keys_indexable=title,bucket_type
node_auto_indexing=true
relationship_auto_indexing=true
```

After that, using a rails console:

```
neo = Neography::Rest.new
neo.create_node_index("node_auto_index", "fulltext", "lucene")
```

I can see the index in the webadmin, but querying data:

```
localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/node_auto_index/name/test_name
```

does not return any data.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: when, how did you add the data? before creating the index? Can you show the code-snippet that actually adds data?

Comment: And you don't index the name property, but the title property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an index doesn't add older data to the index. This has to be done manually.