# Neo4j Automatic Indexing using Neography

Tags: neo4j, neography

Trying to implement auto_indexing using the details gleaned from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048775/neo4j-auto-indexing-for-a-rest-server)

Not really getting any success in retrieving nodes using the index.

My neo4j.properties:

```
node_keys_indexable=title,bucket_type,username
node_auto_indexing=true
relationship_auto_indexing=true
relationship_keys_indexable=since
```

This is what I do to create the node. The node creation works.

```
user = Neo.create_node({:class_name => "User", :username => "foobar1"})
```

This is what I do to find the node using the index:

```
start user=node:node_auto_index(username = 'foobar1') return user
```

doesnt return anything. Any ideas why? Any way to inspect the contents of an index?

Comment: One way to inspect the contents of an index would be to query it in the object browser of the Web Dashboard. But this query didn't return any results either
node:index:node_auto_index:username:*
Even though I can verify that the index exists by looking at the 'Index Manager' section of the Web dashboard

Comment: what version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: I think the config syntax changed after 1.6 can you try the older: node_autoindexing_enabled=true instead?

Comment: didn't help. Ill try upgrading to 1.7 then

Comment: Upgrading to 1.7 didnt make it work either. OTOH, the commented-out property in the template neo4.properties that got installed with 1.7 mentions 'node_autoindexing_enabled' not 'node_autoindexing'. Is the latter the newer value or is it just a leftover reference ?

Comment: it is node_auto_indexing the 1.7 properties file is wrong in this account, is is changed in master for 1.8

Comment: did you try to add the node with the title property in web-admin to see if it works there? and node_auto_indexing (with 2 slashes) should work